# Log to WCF End-to-End trace?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, logging, trace

Is it possible to log messages from the service implementation code to the E2ETrace so that the logmessages are inserted correctly in the callgraph in Microsoft Service Trace Viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751917.aspx

Comment: Any idea on how to achieve the same using WCF REST/Data Services (OData).  Asked the same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402179/how-to-do-end-to-end-tracing-using-wcf-rest-and-or-wcf-data-services